# Is it possible to change the behavior of close button?

Tags: customization, window-buttons

Can I change the behavior of the close button so it won't close the application/window but merely minimize it? Similarly to the behavior in Mac OS X..

Edit: A nice workaround would be to change the behavior of the 'x' button so it will minimize the window/application

Edit (even better?): When clicking the 'x' the window will be closed but the application won't exit... Does it make sense?

Comment: I think what you are describing is exactly what the minimize button does in Ubuntu Unity. Do you specifically want the close button to be the one to do this?

Comment: Good point... Yes... :) I seems like this is what I'm after...

Comment: Looks like I misinterpreted your response when I posted my answer, sorry about that! While my instinct is that this isn't possible, someone who knows more than me might have an answer, so good luck!

Comment: @Dror so are you still looking to make the `X` button minimize the window? Or are you good with using the dedicated `-` minimize button?

Comment: Let's start with 'x' not closing but minimizing. That's more important.

Comment: `When clicking the 'x' the window will be closed but the application won't exit` like for example UGet, Pidgin, and many others.. So yes, possible, but not that I can say how.. You want that for Nautilus or something else?

Comment: Pidgin is one of the annoying examples indeed :)

Comment: I need that for just stopping the applications processes and resuming them afterwards. Just need to run a user-defined command if the button is pressed - how do I do that?